# Add Hover CSS to table cells processed in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm currently using the below code to colour the cells based on their value:

```
cell.each(function() {
            var cell_value = $(this).html();
            if (cell_value == 0){
                $(this).css({'background' : '#DF0101'});  
            } else if ((cell_value >= 1) && (cell_value <=10)) {
                $(this).css({'background' : '#FF7C00'});
            } else if (cell_value >= 8) {
                $(this).css({'background' : '#04B404'});
            }
        });
```

I've also added the CSS to the stylesheet:

```
td:hover{
background-color:#CA2161;}
```

So how can I make it so that on hover the cells processed in the javascript will change colour? At the minute they won't change at all, they just stay as the colour processed above^^^

Comment: In your JS, assign the `background-color` property, not the `background` property. i.e. `$(this).css({'background-color' : '#DF0101'});`

Comment: Work with css classes for each different background color, then add a specific colour for each of those classes with the pseudo selector ``:hover``

Comment: techfoobar, this didn't accomplish what I require. The hover factor still doesn't work.

Kippie, what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Turns out you want the colors to leave instead of show when you hover. Simple change.

Okay first of all, you should separate these out into CSS classes:

```
.ZeroValue {
    background:'#DF0101';
}

.ValueBetween1And10 {
    background:'#FF7C00';
}

.ValueOver8 {
    background:'#04B404';
}

.ValueTransparent {
    background:transparent !important;
}
```

Add the above classes on `$(document).ready()` based on their values:

```
if(cell_value === 0){
    cell.addCLass('ZeroValue');
} else if((cell_value >= 1) && (cell_value <= 10)){
    cell.addClass('ValueBetween1And10');
} else if(cell_value >= 8){
    cell.addClass('ValueOver8');
}
```

Then just dynamically add the `transparent` class when you hover, removing it when you leave:

```
cell.on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).addClass('ValueTransparent');
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ValueTransparent');
    }
});
```

Or if there was a unique color to each item and you wanted to temporarily remove that, you would just create a function:

```
function classByValue(cell,cell_value){
    if(cell_value === 0){
        cell.addCLass('ZeroValue');
    } else if((cell_value >= 1) && (cell_value <= 10)){
        cell.addClass('ValueBetween1And10');
    } else if(cell_value >= 8){
        cell.addClass('ValueOver8');
    }
}
```

This will clear any of the classes when the mouse enters, and then re-add the class based on `cell_value` when mouse enters. Then dynamically apply on load and when `mouseleave`. The `$(document).ready()`:

```
cell.each(function(){
    classByValue(this,this.val());
});
```

And the hover:

```
cell.on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ZeroValue ValueBetween1And10 ValueOver8');
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        classByValue($(this),$(this).val());
    }
});
```

There you have it, multiple ways to accomplish your goal. You might need to modify `$(this).val()` to appropriately reflect the value of that specific `cell`, but without your HTML I can't really determine that.

As a side, that last option with `>= 8` should probably be reconsidered, because a value of `8` or `9` will never fire it.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood slightly, currently the cells are the colour depending on what their value is all the time. I want them to be that colour all the time EXCEPT for when on hover, I want it to change to #CA2161, then when the mouse leaves I want it to change back to the original colour.

Comment: ah, i gotchya. updated my answer for a couple of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to bind an hover function to the "tds" of your table like this

```
      $('td').hover(function(){
           $(this).css('background-color', '#CA2161');
      });
```

and if you want to remove the colour on mouse out you can try this

```
      $( "td" ).hover(
           function() {
          $(this).css('background-color', '#CA2161');
       }, function() {
         $(this).css('background-color', '');
        }
      );
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want. The only problem is that it also removes the original colour that was assigned to the cell based on its value.